# Add parameter to every API request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I need to add an authentification-token to every request I send to my JSON API.

How can I add it via the Adapter?

Comment: Have you tried http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_custom-http-headers ?

Comment: It's easier to attack this from jquery's standpoint.  Ember Data's store utilizes the jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery.ajaxPrefilter (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/)

Here is an example:
http://log.simplabs.com/post/57702291669/better-authentication-in-ember-js#gist6499654

```
Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  if (!jqXHR.crossDomain) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-AUTHENTICATION-TOKEN', App.Session.get('authToken'));
  }
});
```

Add this code to an initializer or create a new one for this (e.g. ajax-initializer).

Answer (score 1):

If attaching it to the URL is fine, you can subclass the adapter (as you requested) by overriding the buildURL method, and then attaching it to the result. For authorization, I would go for EntspAndi's answer, but more common (for someone that finds this SO question using the question title), something like this works fine, too:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
    buildURL: function(type, id, record){
      console.log("Building URL: ", type);
      var url = this._super(type, id, record);
      url += "?extraparam=1"

      return url
    }

  });
```